# Graph Api call to show user's accounts (pages and applications) just returns an empty array?

Tags: facebook, api

I am trying to get a list of my pages and applications using the corresponding Graph API call *users/accounts* `http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/accounts`.

However I just recieve an empty array despite of having pages created on my personal account.

I am successfully authenticated with all access rights I can assign vía my personal account configuration page.

According to the API Docs the required permissions to access the `user/accounts` info is

> manage_pages yields access_tokens that can be used to query the Graph API on behalf of the app/page

But what does that mean in terms of granting permissions? Is there any special permission step required to see the real data instead of an empy array?

Comment: You should definitely read about the Authentication flows in the Facebook api docs ;-) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ You always need to request permissions from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) documentation - you need an access_token with `manage_pages` permission in order to access a user's list of pages and retrieve the page access token for one of them